# Issues with PortletSession on Weblogic running Liferay

Tags: session, session-variables, portlet, liferay-6, weblogic-10.x

I'm having trouble getting my web portlets to run that rely on PortletSession

Any references to the PortletScope like this

request.getPortletSession().getAttribute(name, scope)

or this

request.getAttribute(PortletRequest.USER_INFO

throws the following error

```
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Current request is not a portlet request
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:581)
```

All these portlets work fine in another Portlet container (in Glassfish) but when I try to move them to Weblogic, I get the above errors.

I'm wondering if I need to make any specific changes to the weblogic.xml or the settings of the Weblogic server to get Liferay's ProtletScope to work again.

Any insights on this would be appreciated!

Comment: I posted a similar issue at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21918640/current-request-is-not-a-portlet-request-error-running-liferay-portlets-on-web